# Using delete_post_meta for deleting multiple selected options

Tags: plugin-development, post-meta

I have multiple selected box within my nav menus i used `add_post_meta()` for adding values and `delete_post_meta` for deleting selected options. the code work, means add and delete options correctly but i have small problem

When i delete options `delete_post_meta()` delete selected options except the first one means also remain one of them and i can't delete it

How i can manage this code below until delete all selected options?

```
if(!empty($_REQUEST['menu-item-custom-category'][$menu_item_db_id])) {
    delete_post_meta($menu_item_db_id, '_menu_item_custom_category');
    $values = $_REQUEST['menu-item-custom-category'][$menu_item_db_id];
    foreach($values as $value) {
        add_post_meta($menu_item_db_id, '_menu_item_custom_category', $value);
    }
}

$item->custom_category = get_post_meta( $item->ID, '_menu_item_custom_content');
```

This is my multiple select box

```
<p class="field-custom-category description description-thin">
<label for="edit-menu-item-custom-category-<?php echo $item_id; ?>">
    <?php _e( 'Custom Categories' ); ?><br />
    <select name="menu-item-custom-category[<?php echo $item_id; ?>][]" id="edit-menu-item-custom-category-<?php echo $item_id; ?>" class="widefat code edit-menu-item-custom-category" multiple>
        <?php
            $YPE_cats = get_categories();
            foreach ($YPE_cats as $YPE_cat) { ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $YPE_cat->slug; ?>"  <?php echo selected(in_array($YPE_cat->slug, $item->custom_category)); ?>><?php echo $YPE_cat->name;?></option><?php
            }
        ?>
    </select>
</label>
</p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is just a matter of logic. If you don't select any value, `$_REQUEST['menu-item-custom-category'][$menu_item_db_id]` is empty. So, the next line `delete_post_meta()` is never triggered in your code. Just think in the logic you need to know when to delete previous meta value.

For example:

```
if( !empty( $_REQUEST['menu-item-custom-category'][$menu_item_db_id] ) ) {

    // Delete all previous values from database and save
    // only the selected values in the current request
    delete_post_meta( $menu_item_db_id, '_menu_item_custom_category' );

    $values = $_REQUEST['menu-item-custom-category'][$menu_item_db_id];

    if( is_array( $values ) ) {
        // We have several values
        // Sanitize values first (needed if you have not registered a sanitization callback with register_meta())
        $values = array_map( 'sanitize_text_field', wp_unslash( $_REQUEST['menu-item-content-multiple'][$menu_item_db_id] ) );
        foreach( $values as $value ) {
            add_post_meta( $menu_item_db_id, '_menu_item_custom_category', $value );
        }
    } else {
        // We have single value
        add_post_meta( $menu_item_db_id, '_menu_item_custom_category', sanitize_text_field( $values ) );
    }

} else {

    // All values unselected, delete all of them from post meta
    delete_post_meta($menu_item_db_id, '_menu_item_custom_category');

}
```

This could be optimized, so only new values are added and only deselected values are deleted, without deleting and adding everything everytime. For example (based on [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/107556/37428)):

```
if ( empty( $_REQUEST['menu-item-content-multiple'][$menu_item_db_id] ) ) {

   // no values selected, delete all post meta for our key
   delete_post_meta( $menu_item_db_id, '_menu_item_content_multiple' );

} else {

  $old_values = get_post_meta( $menu_item_db_id, '_menu_item_custom_category' );
  $new_values = $_REQUEST['menu-item-content-multiple'][$menu_item_db_id] 
  $values_to_skip = array();

  if( !empty( $old_values ) ) {

    foreach( $old_values as $old_value ) {

      if ( ! in_array( $old_value, $new_values ) ) {

        // this value was in meta, but now it is not selected,
        // so it has to be deletec
        delete_post_meta( $menu_item_db_id, '_menu_item_custom_category', $old_value );

      } else {

        // This value was in meta and it is selected again,
        // So, we don't need to save it again
        $values_to_skip[] = $old_value;

      }
    }
  }

  // Get the values that are not already in database
  // And store them
  $values_to_save = array_diff( $new_values, $values_to_skip );

  if ( ! empty( $values_to_save ) ) {

    foreach ( $values_to_save as $value ) {

       add_post_meta( $menu_item_db_id, '_menu_item_content_multiple', $value );

    }
  }
}
```

Comment: your method work but little bit more code i tested your code worked with me thanks for you you helped me alot i used `in_array()` php function instead of `!empty()` function as suggested in SAFEEN 1990 answer

Comment: `is_array()` and `empty()` do different things; I would use `empty()` in your case, or maybe both, but not `is_array()` alone because, for example, `is_array()` doesn't check if the array is empty or not and it is important to know if the array is empty or not. Although you can get similar results for a while, using only `is_array() in your case is not appropiate and you can end up deleting meta data incorrectly in some situations. The second option with more code is also more reliable, as you delete/add only the needed values and not all them every time. But it is your choice.

Comment: Also, the other answer does not delete previously selected values but deselected in the current request; so, if you select a value, it will be always soted the meta data until you deselect everything, because deselecting everything is the only situation where post meta is deleted. Definetily, that answer doesn't seem good for me. But, again, it is your choice.

Comment: Answer updated using both checks, `is_array()` and `empty()`, I hope you undestand what I mean; basically you don't need to delete all previous values of your meta filed based on data type but based on **data content**. In almost every case, data type can help to decide how to process the data but not to decide when to save, update or delete it.

Comment: you wright i used the second option `if(empty){}` it is work and delete any option if i want to delete it from selected list and directly delete it from the meta key. again thank you also your answer it is amazing and 100%100 correct

Comment: I want use your answer over three fields does i can use `foreach()` loop to do this? i have these three fields `content_multiple`, `custom_category` and `custom_tag`

Comment: Of course, you can organize your code whatever you want. If you need to repeat the same code three times, a `foreach` loopt can help to keep you [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself).

Answer (score 0):

Before selecting any value you don't have an `array()` means you must select options until the  `$_REQUEST['menu-item-custom-category'][$menu_item_db_id]` became to an `array()`. for checking this must use php `is_array()` function.

Then when you deselect the options that means the `$_REQUEST['menu-item-custom-category'][$menu_item_db_id])` not stay as an array. Then in this case the `delete_post_meta()` work and delete all options in your specified `_menu_item_content_multiple` meta key

means you must use `if()` and `else{}` php conditional statement as below

```
<?php
    if(is_array($_REQUEST['menu-item-content-multiple'][$menu_item_db_id])) {
        $values = $_REQUEST['menu-item-content-multiple'][$menu_item_db_id];
        foreach($values as $value) {
            add_post_meta($menu_item_db_id, '_menu_item_content_multiple', $value);
        }
    } else {
        delete_post_meta($menu_item_db_id, '_menu_item_content_multiple');
    }
?>
```

Comment: Thanks this method work perfectly and it is short method i used this way worked with me and delete all selected options

Comment: When you deselect ALL options, the request data is empty, that is the important thing, **not the data type**. Note that the request can be empty and can be an array at the same time, and viceversa, so your code can end up with unexpected results. Assuming that, if there are value, it is always an array, implies to trust in user input, something dangerous. For example, with this request `menu-item-content-multiple[254][]=&foo=bar` all values are unselected, but your code will do nothing. Also, your code won't update the meta data correctly if not ALL but only some values are deselected.

Comment: it is work but must deselect all selected options to delete. not delete options one by one. for example if i selected three options and i want delete one of theme i can't and must i select all three options and delete them