# Term Meta - saving multiple values in one form with select options

Tags: dashboard, term-meta

I have a working method for adding Term Meta for Taxonomy Terms. CPT is **'houses'** and Taxonomy is **'house_feature'**. This is my code...

First, possible values in an array:

```
$feature_groups = array(
    'bedroom'   =>  __( 'Bedroom', 'genesis' ),
    'living'    =>  __( 'Living Room', 'genesis' ),
    'kitchen'   =>  __( 'Kitchen', 'genesis' )
);
```

Then, extend the WordPress Term Edit Form, using the  {$taxonomy}_add_form_fields Hook dinamically:

```
add_action( 'house_feature_add_form_fields', 'add_feature_group_field', 10, 2 );
function add_feature_group_field( $taxonomy ) {

    global $feature_groups;

    ?>
    <div class="form-field term-group">
        <label for="feature-group"><?php _e( 'Feature Group', 'genesis' ); ?></label>
        <select class="postform" id="equipment-group" name="feature-group">
            <option value="-1"><?php _e( 'none', 'genesis' ) ?></option>
        <?php foreach ( $feature_groups as $_group_key => $_group ) : ?>

            <option value="<?php echo $_group_key; ?>" class=""><?php echo $_group; ?></option>

        <?php endforeach; ?>
        </select>
    </div>
    <?php

}
```

Then, save the Term Meta using the created_{$taxonomy} Hook, so it is 'created_house_feature':

```
add_action( 'created_house_feature', 'save_feature_meta', 10, 2 );
function save_feature_meta( $term_id, $tt_id ) {

    if ( !empty( $_POST['feature-group'] ) ) {

        $group = sanitize_title( $_POST['feature-group'] );
        add_term_meta( $term_id, 'feature-group', $group, true );

    }

}
```

The update routine using {$taxonomy}_edit_form_fields Hook to get the Field for the group into the Edit Form:

```
add_action( 'house_feature_edit_form_fields', 'edit_feature_group_field', 10, 2 );
function edit_feature_group_field( $term, $taxonomy ) {

    global $feature_groups;

    // Get current group.
    $feature_group = get_term_meta( $term->term_id, 'feature-group', true );

    ?>
    <tr class="form-field term-group-wrap">
        <th scope="row"><label for="feature-group"><?php _e( 'Feature Group', 'genesis' ); ?></label></th>
        <td>
            <select class="postform" id="feature-group" name="feature-group">
                <option value="-1"><?php _e( 'none', 'genesis' ); ?></option>
                <?php foreach ( $feature_groups as $_group_key => $_group ) : ?>

                    <option value="<?php $_group_key; ?>" <?php selected( $feature_group, $_group_key ); ?>><?php echo $_group; ?></option>

                <?php endforeach; ?>

            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <?php

}
```

Save the edited data hooking into edited_{$taxonomy}:

```
add_action( 'edited_house_feature', 'update_feature_meta', 10, 2 );
function update_feature_meta( $term_id, $tt_id ) {

    if ( !empty( $_POST['feature-group'] ) ) {

        $group = sanitize_title( $_POST['feature-group'] );

        update_term_meta( $term_id, 'feature-group', $group );

    }

}
```

Display Term Meta data in a new column in the Term list table:

```
add_filter( 'manage_edit-house_feature_columns', 'add_feature_group_column' );
function add_feature_group_column( $columns ) {

    $columns['feature_group'] = __( 'Group', 'genesis' );

    return $columns;

}
```

Adding the content into the Column Fields, we can use the Hook pattern manage_{$taxonomy}_custom_column:

```
add_filter( 'manage_house_feature_custom_column', 'add_feature_group_column_content', 10, 3 );
function add_feature_group_column_content( $content, $column_name, $term_id ) {

    global $feature_groups;

    if ( $column_name !== 'feature_group' ) {
        return $content;
    }

    $term_id        = absint( $term_id );
    $feature_group  = get_term_meta( $term_id, 'feature-group', true );

    if ( ! empty( $feature_group ) ) {
        $content .= esc_attr( $feature_groups[ $feature_group ] );
    }

    return $content;

}
```

Make the group column sortable:

```
add_filter( 'manage_edit-house_feature_sortable_columns', 'add_feature_group_column_sortable' );
function add_feature_group_column_sortable( $sortable ) {

    $sortable['feature_group'] = 'feature_group';

    return $sortable;

}
```

Right, all this comes from a tutorial which works just fine. This code creates, edits, saves and deletes only one value that you may select. I would like to be able to select more than one value in a multiselect.
My question is: how can I make a `<select multiple...>` and be able to save, update, etc every multiple values selected?
Also, can they be shown in the columns?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can shorten your if checks if you use `!empty(` instead of `isset` and `'' !=`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution, all credit goes to @gmazzap, who gave this great answer in this post: [How do I save each option in a multiple select menu as it's own meta_key + meta_value pair?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/107486/how-do-i-save-each-option-in-a-multiple-select-menu-as-its-own-meta-key-meta)

```
add_action( 'created_house_feature', 'save_house_feature_meta', 10, 2 );
function save_house_feature_meta( $term_id, $tt_id ) {

    $old_feature_group = get_term_meta( $term->term_id, 'feature-group, true' );
    $new_feature_groups = isset( $_POST['feature-group'] ) ? $_POST['feature-group'] : array();

    if ( empty( $new_feature_group ) ) {

        // No Feature Groups selected. Then, completely delete all Meta values for the Term.
        delete_term_meta( $term_id, 'feature-group' );

    } else {

        $already_feature_group = array();

        if ( ! empty( $old_feature_group ) ) {

            foreach ( $old_feature_group as $value_feature_group ) {

                if ( ! in_array( $value_feature_group, $new_feature_group ) ) {

                    // This value was selected, but now it isn't, so delete it.
                    delete_term_meta( $term_id, 'feature-group', $value_feature_group );

                } else {

                    // This value is already saved, we can skip it from saving.
                    $already_feature_group[] = $value_feature_group;

                }

            }

        }

        // We don't save what is already saved.
        $to_save_feature_group = array_diff( $new_feature_group, $already_feature_group );

        if ( ! empty( $to_save_feature_group ) ) {

            foreach ( $to_save_feature_group as $feature_group ) {

                add_term_meta( $term_id, 'feature-group', $feature_group, false );

            }

        }

    }

}
```